# Rails haml, table, how to set td min width?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, html-table

I am trying to layout out a form using a table. I use rails and haml.
I have the code below but I can't get the min_width to work - the text "min_width", etc. actually show up in the page.

```
  %table
    %tr 
      %td min_width => "100px;"
      ='aaa'   
      %td.field  
        = f.input :last_name, :label => '&nbsp;'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line

```
%td min_width => "100px;"
```

to

```
%td{:min_width => "100px;"}
```

Comment: also more Dunkin Donuts was required ;)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is kind of old.  @matt's answer put me on the right track, but I ended up having to use:

```
%td{:style => "min-width:100px;"}= ColumnName
```